# How to create multiple data frames from a list of html data?

Tags: python, html, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping

I have the following code to pull data from a website that has multiple pages and then turn the html tables into a dataframe. However the code I have below takes the last table of the html data so I don't get the full result.

I have some code at the bottom of the page s = Scraper(urlsList[0]) that accesses the list urlsList defined above it. What I can't figure out is how to create essentially a loop to create dataframes for each point in the list(0,1,2,3.. etc). So say when the following code is run:

```
s = Scraper(urlsList[n]) #n being the url page number
df
```

A separate dataframe is produced for each n.

At the moment I have a for loop which goes through the page numbers in the url 1 by 1.

Unfortunately I can't share the real URL as it requires authentication but I've made one up to show how the code functions.

```
import io

import urllib3
import pandas as pd
from requests_kerberos import OPTIONAL, HTTPKerberosAuth


a = get_mwinit_cookie()

pageCount = 6 
urlsList = []
urls=
urls = https://example-url.com/ABCD/customer.currentPage={}&end


for x in range(pageCount)[1:]:
    urlsList.append(urls.format(x))


def Scraper(url):
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    with requests_retry_session() as req:
        resp = req.get(url,
                        timeout=30,
                        verify=False,
                        allow_redirects=True,
                        auth=HTTPAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL),
                        cookies=a)


    
    global df
    #data = resp.text
    data = pd.read_html(resp.text, flavor=None, header=0, index_col=0)
    #resp.text, flavor=None, header=0, index_col=0
    df = pd.concat(data, sort=False)
    #df = data
    print(df)

s = Scraper(urlsList[0])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your scraper function. Then you can collect the data from the pages in a list of DataFrames and use `pd.concat()` on that list.

```
def Scraper(url):
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    with requests_retry_session() as req:
        resp = req.get(url,
                        timeout=30,
                        verify=False,
                        allow_redirects=True,
                        auth=HTTPAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL),
                        cookies=a)
    
    return pd.read_html(resp.text, flavor=None, header=0, index_col=0)[0]

pages_data = []
for url in urlsList:
    pages_data.append(Scraper(url))

df = pd.concat(pages_data, sort=False)
```

Comment: Its picking up pages_data as a list which it says then can't be concated. Is there a way before defining df that each point in the list pages_data can be converted to a df and then concated after? @joAschauer

Comment: hmm `pages_data` should be a list of DataFrames because Scraper returns a DataFrame. A list of DataFrames should be able to be concatenated by `pd.concat()`. Can you have a look at the elements in the `pages_data` list?

Comment: I ran: all(v is None for v in pages_data) and it returned none for all elements which is very strange but I do get all the data returned if I run s = [Scraper(urls) for urls in urlsList]

Comment: I think I'm understanding the problem a bit better now. Once its gone through the Scarper function it produces a none type so it can't then be concatenated. I think I'd have to set up an original function the loops for all the urls to create a set of data frames. At the moment I'm just not too sure how to do that. @joAschauer

Comment: i broke up the list comprehension in a loop to make things clearer. Be careful [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) will already return a list of dfs. I changed the Scraper function to only return the first table of your html page.

Comment: I tried this and it potentially works but the only issue I'm now having is that I'm getting an error saying 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'. I think this is because the code is trying to establish several connections at once. I'm currently researching how to fix this